Can not print Chinese characters with bopomofo in the PDF Dart Package
Can not print Chinese characters with bopomofo in the PDF Dart Package
I used the following code to create a PDF with a TrueType font, BpmfIansui-Regular.ttf.
I got several errors saying that "flutter: Unable to find a font to draw "" (U+e01e1) try to provide a TextStyle.fontFallback"
This font works well in the Microsoft Word. It can display the Bopomofo together with
Traditional Chinese character. Any suggestion is welcome.
final textToPrint = processedUnicode;
final pdf = pw.Document();

try {
    debugPrint('Loading font data...');
    final font = await rootBundle.load("lib/assets/fonts/BpmfIansui-Regular.ttf");
    final ttf = pw.Font.ttf(font);  

    debugPrint('Font loaded, generating PDF...');
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return pw.Center(
            child: pw.Text(textToPrint, style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf, fontSize: 24)),
          );
        },
      ),
    );        
} catch (e) {
    debugPrint("Error loading font or generating PDF: $e");
}

